# Как в Sql Server откатить восстановленную базу

Tags: sql, sql-server

Проблема такая: Была у нас рабочая база с данными. Модель восстановления "Простая". Вчера хотел восстановить и подключить эту базу для региона под другим именем и с пустыми данными я отвлекся и забыл задать др. имя базе и нажать Ок и база восстановилась в рабочую базу. Копия базы есть она очень старая и рабочая база обновляется каждый час подскажите как откатить базу назад? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Админы делятся на тех кто не делает бэкапы, и тех кто уже делает. Вы затёрли данные необратимо.

Comment: Восстановление не приводит к удалению бэкапа. Так что на последний бэкап можно восстановиться. А вот всё после утрачено безвозвратно. @SergeyGornostaev Админы делятся на тех, кто делает бэкапы, и тех, кто их будет делать.

Comment: @Akina насколько я понял бэкап есть только протухший, а боевая база перезаписана левыми данными.

Comment: Я пробовал восстанавливать базу из журнала транзакции но как пишет документация из простой модели восстановления не возможно оказывается.